# Strange behavior with .txt files in Doom Emacs

Tags: hooks, visual-line-mode

In Doom Emacs, I have `(add-hook 'text-mode-hook 'visual-line-mode t)` in my `config.el` file.

Files with a `.txt` extension act strangely, though. When the file is first opened, `visual-line-mode` is respected and the text is displayed correctly. But as soon as I add a word to a line, Emacs inserts a bunch of hard linebreaks at around the 80-column mark. I can rejoin the pieces of the line with `J` (Doom uses vim bindings) and `visual-line-mode` is once again followed. But as soon as I start typing again, the hard linebreaks are added again.

Mysteriously, this doesn't happen in `org` files, which display and behave correctly from the get-go.

My work-around has been to remove the `.txt` extension from text files and hit `SPC t w` to toggle `visual-line-mode` on when I open them. Everything goes swimmingly after that.

This is not optimal, though. `visual-line-mode` already works just fine with `org` files. I just need to get it to treat files with the `.txt` extension the same way.

Comment: Do you see the same thing if you start Emacs with `emacs -Q`? If not, bisect your init file to find the culprit.

Comment: You also need to disable auto-fill-mode in the same hook.

Comment: How do I disable auto-fill-mode in that hook?